# IIS 7.5, ASP.NET third party assemblies in /Bin not being found (Error CS0246)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express

I'm relatively new to IIS and ASP.NET development, and have been hopelessly lost searching for an answer to this for some time now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiALm.jpg

To get to the point, my company's third party .dll files are not being found in the Bin folder (or so it seems). The project has always built fine in VS 2012 on my machine. Other .dlls of third parties *are* working however.

I have tried referencing my assemblies directly in my web.config file, as well as placing them into the GAC.

(From what I understand) I have configured IIS and the app pool to use the correct versions of .NET, and the server is serving just plain html fine.

Is there something basic I have missed?

Comment: you site is run from your desktop ? probably you do not have set the correct permissions, missing the correct version, did not have install the `System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll`

Comment: May be your third party dll is 32bit dll and you are running app pool in 64bit. Enable 32bit applications using app pool's advanced settings option.

Comment: It looks like you are referencing x86 assemblies from x64 or vice versa. On assembly resolve it cannot find the assemblies event though they are deployed. Ensure to build to the correct platform and not Any CPU.